# Get correct route url data when url routing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, global-asax

I am doing route url for SEO. 
But while I am getting route data, this error occurs; "404 - File or directory not found."

URL;

```
http://subdomain.callcenter.com/ActivateUser/speu2mziTcVs+O3NCQZtWAFX2lWecxotSfAOXu1TEQ=
```

But when I removed '+' character from route data string it works great.

My global.asx file;

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("ActivateUser", "ActivateUser/{*code}", "~/Presentation/Site/ActivateUser.aspx");
```

what is the problem?

Comment: An interesting thing; it works in local but when I published to it a website, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is changing web.config as below;

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```